# Can we have multiple c files to define functions for one header file?

Tags: c++, c, linker

Newbie to C and C++.

I have one .h file in which some functions are declared.
I'm trying to implement the functions in two separate .c files, but when compiling I got a linker error.

Is it not allowed?

Comment: Please [edit] and show how you compile along with the verbatim error log. And possibly add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is allowed. Here is a very simple example:

**foobar.h**: declares `foo` and `bar`

```
void foo(void);
void bar(void);
```

**foo.c**: implements `foo`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foobar.h"

void foo(void)
{
  printf("foo\n");
}
```

**bar.c**: implements `bar`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foobar.h"

void bar(void)
{
  printf("bar\n");
}
```

**main.c**: uses `foo` and `bar`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foobar.h"

int main(void) {
  foo();
  bar();
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling, linking and running with gcc:

```
$ gcc foo.c
$ gcc bar.c
$ gcc main.c
$ gcc -o someprog foo.o bar.o main.o
$ ./someprog
foo
bar
$
```

or

```
$ gcc -o someprog foo.c bar.c main.c
$ ./someprog
foo
bar
$
```